# CORS post index file with XML call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, url, cors

I have some Ajax that makes a Cross Origin Resource call

```
 $("#inductive1").click(function (event) {
    $.post(
       "https://www.mysite.co.uk/folder/tests/Inductive/Test1/index.phtml",
        function (data) {
            $('.stage2').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

within the `index.phtml` file I have some Script that calls `exam.xml`

**Script inside index.phtml**

```
( function($, undefined) {

            $(function() {

                var test = new Test({

                    testName: "Inductive Test 1",
                    dataURL : "/getresultshtml.php",
                    sendEmailURL: "/sendresultsbyemail.php",
                    contentFolder : "./",
                    solutionURL: "../../../content/f/id/10/",
                    userID: 0,
                    courseItemID: 25,
                    XMLFile: "exam.xml",
                    isStandalone: false
                });

                test.start();

            });
        }(jQuery));
```

However the xml file is trying to be called from the other server,

EG

```
https://server1.com/exam.xml
```

it should be

```
https://myserver.com/exam.xml
```

I have tried changing the JS to direct path as in

```
 XMLFile: "htttps:/myserver.com/exam.xml"
```

but it is being read as

```
https://server1.com/myserver.com/exam.xml
```

how do I change the javascript so that it changes the root URL to `myserver.com` and not `server1.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some plugin you are using is changing document's base URL,
you can try putting this at the beginning of index.phtml

```
<base href="https://myserver.com">
```

If that doesn't work you might need to dynamically change the base property through JavaScript just before the ajax call

```
document.write("<base href='http://myserver.com/'>");
```

Comment: WOw this looks good. love the 1 line fixes, just got a new error im fixing then if works ill accept the answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure of how `Test` might be changing root path but glad it worked ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the `Test` will use the `XMLFile`. But per the [jquery.ajax documentation,](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) passing the complete url (with the protocol) in the `url` parameter should be enough.

Maybe the `test.start()` is doing some manipulation?

The only other possible issue that I found is that you are declaring your protocol with an extra `t` and a missing `/`

```
XMLFile: "htttps:/myserver.com/exam.xml"
```

Try using

```
XMLFile: "https://myserver.com/exam.xml"
```